# Nested Condition in *ngIf using ng-container

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular-ng-if

I am working on requirements where I need to show the list of rows based on some conditions.
There is a table cell(**td**) whose value should be populated based on some condition.
I want the following to achieve in angular using ***ngIf**

```
if(value1||values2)
{
    if(value3!=null && value4==null)
    {
        //display value 3
    }
    else
    {
     //display value 4
    }
}
else
{
//display default value
}
```

Pictorial representation of what I want to achieve [image: Diagram]
I tried this using *ngIf but getting an error  ****Bidings cannot contain assignments** **

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(value1 || value2); else showDefault">
    <ng-container *ngIf="value3!=null && value4==null; else showValue4">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #showValue4>
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #showDefault>
</ng-template>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: you seem to be missing quotes around your first `*ngIf` and a closing quote after your second one

Comment: Yes!! that was a typo mistake. I just updated the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your solution seems fine, another way would be to use the [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#example) directive.

That way you can have your `ngTemplates` ready and decide what you're going to use by the name of the template like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="selected">
  This text is not displayed
</ng-container>

<ng-template #template1>
  <p>This is our template.</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2>
  <p>This is another template.</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template3>
  <p>This is one more template.</p>
</ng-template>

<button (click)="selected = template1" >1</button>
<button (click)="selected = template2" >2</button>
<button (click)="selected = template3" >3</button>
```

[Here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ngtemplateoutlet-in-angular/) you can read more.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zekhbs?file=src/app/app.component.html) I created a StackBlitz, to play around.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But I want to achieve the If else example that I give in the questions. In your example, I can relate only 2 conditions.  Can you provide the same for multi conditions.

Comment: Of course you can! Look at the StackBlitz again: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zekhbs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `NgTemplateOutlet` is a very special feature that Angular provides, I would recommend you to read the articles I shared with you and I am sure that it will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: I have just added the diagram of what I want to achieve using nested conditinos. Is there any way to do this as shown in the diagram.

Comment: If you understand how outlet template works, you can do it on your own. All the information is here...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<ng-container *ngIf="value3 && !value4; else showValue4">
```